# Why do we get the address of AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey in AVCam sample code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading this sample code ([AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)) about AVCaptureSession and etc. And I notice this following line ([link to the code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AAPLCameraViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-AVCam_AAPLCameraViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)):

```
// In iOS 9 and later, the userInfo dictionary contains information
// on why the session was interrupted.
if ( &AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey ) {
   ...
}
```

The comment in the code make sense. But what doesn't make sense to me is why do we want to get the address of `AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey`. It is defined as the following (in AVCaptureSection.h):

```
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

If the key is defined, how will its address be `nil`? If this key is not defined, the code will never be compiled, right? Could someone explain to me how this if statement work?

Comment: Did you got the solution of the above problem??

Comment: @SumitSharma, yes. See the answer below.

Comment: Still not able to get, could you please explain a bit. I have also raised a question, you can answer on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077150/music-app-playing-in-background-breaks-while-recording-video-using-avcapturese

Comment: Hello, @SumitSharma. Your question is totally different than what I am asking here. I may spend sometime trying yours later but no guarantee. If you still have anything that you didn't understand, you may ask rmaddy to clarify it or ask him to take a look at your question directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonKey` was added in iOS 9.0. Such an `if` statement is needed only if your app also supports iOS 8 or earlier.

When the code is run on a device with iOS 9 or later, the value will be non-nil and the `if` statement will be true. On devices with iOS 8 or earlier, the value will be `nil` and the `if` statement will be false.

If your app only supports iOS 9 or later, there is no need for the `if` statement.

Read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i) in the iOS docs for more details on this type of check.