# Music App (playing in background) breaks while recording video using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am working on snapchat app like functionality. In my application, music app is running in the background and my app is in foreground state. I have to capture video simultaneously with music app running in the background.

Problem :- when my app comes in foreground state, the music app audio break for a second and then continue. Same problem arises when user tap **HOME** button,  app went to background state and the music app audio break for a second.

I have downloaded the apple sample code for recording https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

After downloading following changes have been done in the AppDelegate

**In AppDelegate.h**

> import AVFoundation
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain)  AVAudioSession *session1;

**In AppDelegate.m**

> ```
> self.session1 = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
> ```

```
[self.session1 setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
               withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionInterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers error:nil];
[self.session1 setActive:YES error:nil];


// Inform the device that we want to use the device orientation.
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

**In AAPLCameraViewController.m

Two properties have been added**

> self.session.usesApplicationAudioSession=TRUE;
>       self.session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession=FALSE;

---

**Another Way** 
I have tried using **SCRecorder Library** but same issue is coming with that library. Source code can be reached from Github
https://github.com/sumitsharma/SCRecorderDemo

Comment: I think you cannot play music while recording.

Comment: There are many application on Apple store(iTunes) which provide the same feature. Snapchat (https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8),  Vine (https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/vine/id592447445?mt=8)

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?